# How to JSON.parse data in a Meteor template?

Tags: meteor

Here is my scenario, the first project with [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29): I have JSON-stringified data embedded in my MongoDB documents, as you can see in the MESSAGE key below:

```
{ "DATE" : "Jan 24 23:28:14",
  "MESSAGE" : **"{\"status_code\":200,\"uri\":\"172.16.156.143/content/dynamic\",\"tprocess\":3}"**,
  "_id" : ObjectId("5101c3992a1624e726000014") }
```

In Meteor, my client template code looks like the following basic pattern:

```
Template.log.logEntry = function () {
    return Messages.find({});
};
```

... Which works OK, but it'll obviously render the following template...

```
<template name="log">
    <h1>Log Entries Are:</h1>
        {{#each logEntry}}
            <div> : {{MESSAGE}} </div>
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

... With a non-parsed, literal string in the browser, for example,

```
{"status_code":200,"uri":"172.16.156.143/static/style.css","tprocess":2}
```

I'd love to JSON.parse() this string and do more interesting things, but I'm not sure how best to do it from the isClient context in my Meteor project's JavaScript file.

Comment: I noticed you have an ObjectID in there, of note is you can't use this in meteor yet. Its on the roadmap: https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. As of now all I really care about is that MESSAGE field so it'll not interfere with the functionality I'm trying for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a template helper:

```
Template.log.aSpecificField = function () {
  return JSON.parse(this.MESSAGE).aSpecificField;
}
```

which allows you to use `{{aSpecificField}}` within your `#each` loop.

Comment: don't get it, why aSpecificField calls itself?

Comment: I deleted my first comment: I see that this is another method for the one I posted above, and it'll indeed work after spending time with the meteor docs on template helpers. Thanks, will accept this as the answer barring any other ideas that fit better.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona: The 'aSpecificField' property is just the field that you want to extract, eg. Template.log.uri = function(...)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it (indeed, I suspect not), but this works as expected.

```
Template.log.helpers({
  get_uri: function () {
     return JSON.parse(this.MESSAGE).uri;
}
```

Calling it in the template is now just:

```
{{ get_uri }}
```